# Можно ли использовать рекурсию?

Tags: java, алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть задача.   Метод принимает строку (длинную) и должен распечатать ее построчно так, чтобы длина каждой выводимой строки была не больше 13 символов и слова не разбивались (перенос только на пробелах). Сделал через циклы, но как то очень монструозно, вот чувствую, что можно использовать рекурсию, но не могу понять как.

Пример
Ввод

```
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth upon this continent a new nation,conceived in liberty and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal
```

Вывод

```
Four score
and seven
years ago
our fathers
brought
forth upon
this
continent a
new nation,
conceived in
liberty and
dedicated to
the
proposition
that all men
are created
equal
```

Comment: Где Ваше решение?

Comment: Зачем циклЫ? Цикл нужен один, в нем надо помнить начало первого еще нераспечатанного слова и положение предпоследнего найденного пробела.

Comment: Игорь, а можно пример?  А то я немного запутался...

Comment: Сейчас не могу. Позже смогу.

Comment: Igor спасибо, проблема уже решена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот возможное решение на рекурсии:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String source = "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth upon this continent a new nation";
    print(13, source.split("\\s"), 0);
}

static void print(final int length, final String[] tokens, int start) {
    final StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    while (start < tokens.length) {
        final String token = tokens[start];
        if (line.length() == 0 || line.length() + 1 + token.length() < length) {
            start++;
            if (line.length() > 0) {
                line.append(' ');
            }
            line.append(token);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(line.toString());
    if (start < tokens.length) {
        print(length, tokens, start);
    }
}
```

Но, если у вас есть возможность использовать сторонние библиотеки, то советую взять [`WordUtils#wrap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#wrap-java.lang.String-int-):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String source = "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth upon this continent a new nation";
    System.out.println(WordUtils.wrap(source, 13 - 1));
}
```

намного короче и проще. Хочу заметить, что в реализации [`WordUtils#wrap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#wrap-java.lang.String-int-) используются циклы, а не рекурсия, и эта реализация достаточно "монструозна".

Comment: Если использовать входную строку полностью, как я задал, то падает с исключением

Comment: @Tariel Поправил чуть чуть. Заметьте, что в вашей входной строке отсутствует пробел после запятой `nation,conceived`

Comment: Уже разобрался )))    Спасибо большое!!